# What security does the wpa_passphrase tool actually add to a wpa-supplicant configuration file?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, wpa-supplicant

I was looking at [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) guide to setting up a wifi connection on a modern linux system (specifically raspbian, but I assume the steps are similar in other linux systems) with only a command-line interface. The guide mentioned that the PSK could be stored as a pre-encrypted 32 byte hexadecimal number, but also mentioned that a plaintext SSID and PSK will be used to connect. Further, the `wpa_passphrase` tool seems to encrypt the PSK using the SSID (unless I am misinterpreting the tutorial).

If an attacker gained access to this wpa-supplicant configuration file, it seems like he could just use the SSID (stored there in plain text) and knowledge of the `wpa_passphrase` tool's encryption algorithm to decrypt the PSK, giving no more security than storing a plain-text PSK in the file. Is this not the case, and why?

Comment: *"If an attacker gained access to this wpa-supplicant configuration file..."* - Most threat model collapse with this level of compromise. An attacker that has root and can read configuration files can also read state of the random number generator, read decrypted traffic, and do other nefarious things. There's no confidentiality or integrity after that.

Comment: You might also be interested in [Is there a way to configure WPA2-PSK to provide Forward Secrecy?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/40415/29925) Also see [Wi-Fi Protected Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access) and *"WPA and WPA2 don't provide forward secrecy, meaning that once an adverse person discovers the pre-shared key, they can potentially decrypt all packets encrypted using that PSK transmitted in the future and even past..."* It looks like WPA3 is going to close the gap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PSK isn't an encrypted version of your passphrase; it's a *hashed* version of your passphrase. Specifically (if I remember correctly), the PSK in WPA2 is the output of PBKDF2(passphrase) using the SSID as a salt.

The difference is that ciphers are reversible, hashes are not. The PSK is actually *directly usable* as the WPA2 network key, without any decryption at all, but it cannot be reversed to find out the original passphrase.

This only provides mild security on its own, but if you frequently rotate the passphrase (e.g. MyLittleWifi42 → MyLittleWifi43 → MyLittleWifi44), then someone having just the hashed PSK has no way of guessing future passphrases. Similarly, renaming the network also invalidates all old PSKs.

(Note: As far as I know, this method will no longer work with WPA3-SAE, which requires the client to have the original passphrase. Storing just the PSK would limit you to WPA2 only.)

Comment: I didn't realize that the hash was usable as a network key (or even that it was a hash). That clears things up.

Comment: Hashing the passphrase this way is how *all* Wi-Fi devices calculate the network key.

Comment: If it is obtained, it can be used to authenticate, except that the hacker cannot ascertain your original password. I share the OP's confusion. What's it actually FOR?

Comment: @KDM: Do you mean in the protocol over the air, or do you mean in the wpa_supplicant config?